# python3 how list storage bucket in GCP AppEngine via python?

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine-python

I am new in python, and even new in GCP Google Cloud App Engine.
I was testing this script for listing my storage bucket however script responds with no output, even no error, also when I changed bucketname to something not exist name, I got the same results, so its weird.
I am using local OS linux.

```
~/pit$ python main.py 
(env) ~/pit$
```

Here is the script > copied from google https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-objects#storage-list-objects-python

main.py>

```
from google.cloud import storage


def list_blobs(bucket_name):
    """Lists all the blobs in the bucket."""
    bucket_name = "pyton_test_bucket"

    storage_client = storage.Client()

    # Note: Client.list_blobs requires at least package version 1.17.0.
    blobs = storage_client.list_blobs(bucket_name)

    for blob in blobs:
        print(blob.name)
```

Another question is how to implement this list command to my test flask render index template ?
My goal is to render list object in next line after this
`h1>My Fav show is {{ show }}</`
In flask example is showing only how to render 1 value, so I don't know how to proceed here with  Flask.

main.py

```
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')

def hello():
    tv_show="Test"
    return render_template("index.html", show=tv_show)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # This is used when running locally only. When deploying to Google App
    # Engine, a webserver process such as Gunicorn will serve the app. This
    # can be configured by adding an `entrypoint` to app.yaml.
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8080, debug=True)
# [END gae_python37_app]
```

index.html>

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>

        <h1>My Fav show is {{ show }}</h1>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced your use case and deployed to Google App Engine Standard

`app.yaml`

```
runtime: python37

handlers:

  - url: /static
    static_dir: template

  - url: /.*
    secure: always
    redirect_http_response_code: 301
    script: auto
```

`requirements.txt`

```
Flask==1.1.1
google-cloud-storage
```

`main.py`

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
from google.cloud import storage
import os

# If `entrypoint` is not defined in app.yaml, App Engine will look for an app
# called `app` in `main.py`.
app = Flask(__name__)



def get_blobs(bucket_name):
    """Lists all the blobs in the bucket."""

    storage_client = storage.Client()
    # Note: Client.list_blobs requires at least package version 1.17.0.
    blobs = storage_client.list_blobs(bucket_name)
    b = list()
    for blob in blobs:
      b.append(blob.name)

    return b


@app.route('/blobs/<bucket_name>')
def hello(bucket_name):
    """Return a friendly HTTP greeting."""

    print ("Test {}".format(bucket_name))
    return render_template('index.html', blobs=get_blobs(bucket_name))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # This is used when running locally only. When deploying to Google App
    # Engine, a webserver process such as Gunicorn will serve the app. This
    # can be configured by adding an `entrypoint` to app.yaml.
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8080, debug=True)
# [END gae_python37_app]
```

`templates/index.html`

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>All the blobs </h1>
{% for blob in blobs %}
<p>{{ blob }}</p>
{% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

To deploy to App Engine:

```
  gcloud app deploy
  gcloud app browse
  #go to https://your_project.nw.r.appspot.com/blobs/your_bucket
```

[image]

To run this application locally you need to :

1.[Create a service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts) with Storage Admin Role

2.[Set the default credentials](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production)

Comment: OK, I tried to run localy, not needed to deploy yet, but I got this error> `127.0.0.1 - - [15/Apr/2020 18:47:58] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Apr/2020 18:47:59] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
`  
I  set bucket as public for Storage data Viever role, So I hope I dont need any service account, right ?

Comment: I am also little confused with all this python code, can u pls update this basic Hello World flask app to just list the bucket ?
Thank you a lot 
`from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
from google.cloud import storage
import os
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello(): 
    return 'Hello World!'
if __name__ == '__main__':
      app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8080, debug=True)

`

Comment: my public bucket name is `pyton_test_bucket`

Comment: all this python code is need it for listing  the bucket. If you deploy locally, you do not need the requirements.txt and the app.yam. Please mark my answer as accepted if it was useful to you, for better visibility for the community.